# Angle chasing on cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $\textbf{Problem.}$ $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and the tangent to the circle at $D$ intersect $AB$ and $BC$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively. $T$ is a point inside $\triangle ABC$ such that $TE$ is parallel to $CD$ and $TF$ is parallel to $AD$. Say $TE$ and $TF$ intersect $AC$ at $M$ and $N$ respectively, it is given that $AEDM, MTND, DNCF$ are concyclic. $D$ is tangent to both $AEDM$ and $DNCF$. Let $AC$ intersect $TD$ at $L$. Let $BL$ intersect the circumcircle of $MTND$ at $X$. Prove that $NX$ is parallel to $AB$.

---

$\textbf{Attempt:}$ The first thing that came into my mind after drawing the diagram was to somehow use [Reim's theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/Reim1.shtml). If we can prove that $A,D,X$ are collinear then we will be done. Some approaches that can be taken are as follows:

1. Proving $\angle CDX= \angle CAD$ as then bt Alternate Segment Theorem, it would be proven that $X$ lie on $EF$.
2. Proving $\angle TDX + \angle TDE=180°$.
3. Proving $\angle MDE+ \angle MDX= 180°$.
4. Proving $\angle BAN = \angle ANX$.
5. Proving $\angle MDE = \angle MNX$.
   Proving any one of the above claims will solve the problem, however there can be other ways to solve it as well.

I have attached a diagram.[image]

Comment: This post is identical to [one from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4661985/409), although the author's name is different. Please note that re-posting a question is not the appropriate way to call attention to it; rather, the author should edit the original to add new thoughts or further context. (Editing a question will "bump" it to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of a re-post without cluttering the site with duplicates or causing confusion with deletions. That said, non-substantive edits *just* to trigger a bump are discouraged.)

Comment: @Blue the thing is this is my second account which has more than 100 reputation. When that post didn't receive attention, I thought of reposting the question from this account so that I can set a bounty. (That account had less than 50 reputation so I could not a bounty through that account)

Comment: You might want to mention your rationale in the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) Also, you might consider asking a moderator to merge your accounts; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82782), for instance.

Comment: I think you want to show that EDXF are collinear instead? ADX certainly doesn't look collinear. Also, we'd need that CNLA are collinear.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, infact showing EDX collinear is enough as EDF is already collinear. Also, CNLA being collinear is given in the problem.